# Security involved with running a batch file to create Document Libraries

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise, security, file-upload

I was wondering what kind of permission levels should a batch have to execute procedures that create programmatically Document Libraries on SharePoint 2010.

Has someone done that?

Answer (score 1):

The account would need to have Manage Lists permission on the destination site. This is enabled in the Full Control and Design permission levels by default or your own custom permission level could be created.

It is unclear how you want to do this.  Please clarify.